# how to add a checkbox in bootstrap table?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

instead of '#' symbol in this bootstrap table ,i want to add a checkbox ....please also give me any reference from where i can understand how to do such things ,like we have clear documentation for bootstrap table ....i just had to copy that code into my vs code

[image of bootstrap table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We1dW.png)

here is my code that i copied it from this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/ :

```html
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Change `<th scope="col">#</th>` to `<th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" /></th>`

Comment: Did you added Bootstrap 4 CDN in file.

Answer (score 2):

As codeMonkey has already commented ,this worked for me :

> ```
>     <th scope="col">#</th>
> ```

to

> ```
>    <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add CDN in your File and the let me know it is working fine or not.

- Without CDN it is looking same.

  ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  ```